# Virtualbox "no bootable medium found" even with an image?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-95

I am trying to run Windows 95 on Virtualbox but when I try to run it, even though I select the winworld iso, it still says `FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.`

[image: image : https://cutt.ly/guXze3v]

Comment: Do you have a Windows 95 CD you can use (or obtain on eBay)?  I created a Windows 95 VM in VMware this way.

Comment: The rickroll is not necessary. If the link was down (which it was for me), that joke would be a serious annoyance. Don't do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 95 needs a floppy to boot most of it's disk images. it can be found here: https://winworldpc.com/product/microsoft-windows-boot-disk/95-osr2x

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did. When running the machine, go to "Devices > Floppy Drives > Choose a virtual floppy disk" and select your floppy disk file. Then, reboot the virtual machine.